# How to get entity manager in form type

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

How could I get entity manager when building forms?

I would like to search results from the database and build the choices for choicetype.
I know I could use entitytype instead but in this situation I want to record string in database than an object.
And also I need to add some more options as well.

Thank you.

Comment: you can inject entity manager as a form type constructor and pass entity manager when you create form, like 


`$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType($em), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('your_url'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        )); `

Comment: Wow, cool. I will try that later. Currently I just use a private function in controller to build the form instead of previous Form Type. Thanks a lot, habibun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Symfony 3.2 (and possibly others, I'm not sure about 3.1, but it is probably the same), the `$this->createForm()` method needs a string as the first parameter, and cannot take a form object.

Add a `configureOptions` method to your form class:

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'entityManager' => null,
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Entity Manager is set in: $options['entityManager']
    }
}
```

Then get the form in your controller like so, passing in the Entity Manager:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
     YourFormType::class,
     $yourEntity,
     [
         'entityManager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
     ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke, helps me a lot.